# Waiting a certain amount of time before going to the next step

Tags: function, lua, wait, love2d

I'm writing Lua code with the LÖVE framework. Is there anything either can provide to suspend the run of a given function for a certain amount of time?

What I know is that both `love.draw()` and `love.updates()` are usable to keep track of the persistence of time. Should I do something based on this, or is there a simpler way? Probably built-in functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suspending either of those isn't really a good idea. Especially `love.draw`, since that's needed to keep the window up-to-date.

However, if you have some processing that you don't want to do for a specific period of time, that's pretty easy. At the start of that period of time, get the current time. Then, every frame, check to see if the requested elapsed time has passed. Once it has, go back to doing that processing.

```
local function begin_elapsed_wait(time_to_wait)
    local end_time = love2d.timer.getTime() + time_to_wait
    return function()
        if(end_time < love2d.timer.getTime()) then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end

local am_waiting = function() return false end

function love.update(dt)
    if(am_waiting()) then
        return
    end

    --Do stuff.

    if(--[[whatever]]) then
        am_waiting = begin_elapsed_wait(2.5) --do not update for 2.5 seconds
    end
end
```

Comment: I didn't necessarily want to suspend either, but rather a function called within them. Your solution is brilliant, I didn't even remotely have this idea, thank you!